# spring cloud contract dsl specify path parameter

Tags: java, spring, dsl, spring-cloud-contract

I am trying to create a contract for a GET request and I'd like to use a path parameter, that can be reused in the response as well. Is this at all possible? I can only find examples for POST, query parameters and body's. 
So if I want to define a contract that requests an entity i.e. /books/12345-6688, I want to reuse the specified ID in the response.

How do I create a contract for something like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope that's not possible due to https://github.com/tomakehurst/wiremock/issues/383 . Theoretically you could create your own transformer + override the way stubs are generated in Spring Cloud Contract. That way the WireMock stubs would contain a reference to your new transformer (like presented in the WireMock docs - http://wiremock.org/docs/extending-wiremock/). But it sounds like a lot of work for sth that seems not really that necessary. Why do you need to do it like this? On the consumer side you want to test the integration, right? So just hardcode some values in the contract instead of referencing them and just check if you can parse those values.

UPDATE:
If you just need to parametrize the request URL but don't want to reference it in the response you can use regular expressions like here - https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-contract/single/spring-cloud-contract.html#_regular_expressions

UPDATE2:
Like @laffuste has mentioned, starting from RC1 you can reference a concrete path element

Comment: OK. So basically you can only create contracts for POST methods or for a generic GET that retrieves a list? It is nog possible to define a contract for retrieving an item from that list using GET other than just hardcode an identifier in the contract?

Comment: You can use query parameters or regular expressions. You just can't reference the path variables in the response

Comment: Ok, but how do I use a regular expression in the path then?

Comment: You can write `request { url("foo/${regex('[0-9]{3}')}"/bar") }` to have the producer side generated or do it explicitly `request { url($(producer("foo/123/bar"), consumer("foo/${regex('[0-9]{3}')}"/bar")) }`. You can use the short notation too `request { url($(p("foo/123/bar"), c("foo/${regex('[0-9]{3}')}"/bar")) }`. Here you have an example - https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-contract/spring-cloud-contract.html#_regular_expressions

Comment: Thanks! I overlooked that example.

Comment: I've updated the answer. Can you mark it as answered?

Answer (score 7):

Possible since Spring Cloud Contract **1.2.0-RC1** (fixed in [this issue](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-contract/issues/388)).

```
response {
    status 200      
    body(
        path: fromRequest().path(),
        pathIndex: fromRequest().path(1)  // <-- here   
    )
}
```

See the [docs](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-contract/1.2.0.RC1/single/spring-cloud-contract.html#_referencing_the_request_from_the_response).

Comment: Thanks for keeping this answer up to date!